# Product page color filtering - Magento 2.1.7

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, magento-2.1.7

I created a color attribute for my products and gave the filter option in the product category.

I only see 24 colors but I've put in a lot more.
How can I increase the visibility from 24 to all the colors that I have?

[image]

Comment: did you check the height of that particular `<div>` in which Colors are loading.

Comment: It's tried but not the height